# How to fix PUT route that is updating a different id than the one sent in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, json, express, nosql, postman

PUT route updating object with the wrong ID.

I tried changing from `params.id` to `body.id` but it still doesn't change the output. It is updating but is updating only the first object ever creating which doesn't match the id sent.

```
app.put('/:id', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
 const requiredFields = ['destination', 'when', 'lastDayOfTrip'];
  for (let i=0; i<requiredFields.length; i++) {
    const field = requiredFields[i];
    if (!(field in req.body)) {
    const message = `Missing \`${field}\` in request body`
    console.error(message);
    return res.status(400).send(message);
    }
 }

    if (req.params.id !== req.body.id) {
     const message = `Request path id (${req.body.id}) and request 
     body id (${req.body.id}) must match`;
     console.error(message);
     return res.status(400).send(message);
     }

 TripPost
 .update({
    id: req.params.id,
    destination: req.body.destination,
    when: req.body.when,
    lastDayOfTrip: req.body.lastDayOfTrip
 })
 .catch( err => res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something went 
  wrong'}));
 console.log(TripPost)
 res.status(204).end();
 });
```

PUT route is supposed to update object with matching ID. Instead is updating just the first object ever created even tho it's not the ID that was sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it this way:

```
 if (!(req.params.id && req.body.id && req.params.id === req.body.id)) {
        res.status(400).json({
          error: 'Request path id and request body id values must match'
        });
    }

    const updated = {};
    const updateableFields = ['destination', 'when', 'lastDayOfTrip', 
    'tripDetails'];
    updateableFields.forEach(field => {
        if (field in req.body) {
          updated[field] = req.body[field];
        }
    });

    TripPost
        .findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: updated }, { new: true })
        .then(TripPost => res.status(204).end())
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something went wrong' 
         }));
        res.status(204).end();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Please revise your query, update function require two objects, 
 first object is conditional object and the second object should data to be updated.   
 TripPost
 .update({

    _id: req.params.id,     // Please change id to _id in update query
   },
    {
 $set: {   
    destination: req.body.destination,
    when: req.body.when,
    lastDayOfTrip: req.body.lastDayOfTrip
   }
  }})
 .then(tripData=> {
     console.log(tripData) 
      res.status(200).json({ data: tripData}));
   })
 .catch( err => 
   res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something went wrong'}));
 });
```